# 14/2 wire 2 way switch adding 14/3 wire to make it a 3 way

Tags: switch, light

I want to turn a 2 way switch into 3 way with 14/3 wire. I am assuming wire nut the white wires, and put the other wires on the switches.

I bought 2 3 way switches as well.

Comment: Does power come in at the switch or at the light?

Answer (score 4):

On the 14/3 cable, tape the white wire with black electrical tape on both ends. This is always-hot.

Tape the other two wires with yellow tape on both ends. These are travelers.

The reason to mark with tape is a) with white it's the law; and b) with yellow, it turns a typically very confusing 3-way box into *easy mode*. 3-ways are notorious for having no color codes at all, and your next 3-way might have white/red travelers.

In the existing switch box, there should be two wires on the switch.  Whichever one is *always-hot* is attached to the black-taped white wire from the new /3.

Next, in each box, the 2 yellow-taped wires are put on the 2 brass (yellow-ish)  screws on the 3-way switch.

In each box, there should be 1 wire left.  That goes on the black screw of the 3-way.

Comment: Harper's law for travelers-  always yellow.

Comment: You won't confuse them with anything else :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I just took the light switch box apart which is a 2 gang box, and the other switch is a 3 way as well. Is that going to be too many wires for a 2 gang box?

Comment: @Doug21 You have to do a wire-count and compare it to the stamped "cubic inches" on the box in question unless it's a standard size.  Generally you need 2.0 cubic inches per #14 non-ground wire. All grounds count like 1 wire, every switch counts lie 2 wires, pigtails are free. You can search here for Q&A on the exact procedure.

Comment: I couldn't find where its stamped. Probably standard. I removed the drywall behind the gang box, and it was almost touching that drywall. I removed it so I could just add the extra wire if it's not too much for this box. If it is I'll get a 3 gang box, and have 2 switches. How many wires for a standard box?

Comment: @Doug21 There's no such thing as a standard box.  There are plastic boxes, metal ones, you name it.  If it's a 4x4x1.5" steel 2-gang box, that'll be 21 c.i.

Comment: It's a plastic 2 gang box

Comment: So I have 4 wires in the box right now without the new 14/3. The 4 black wires are wire nutted, and 1 is being jumped out into the switch I am making a 3 way.